# SSAS fill missing gaps

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap

lets say I have a fact table like this:

```
ID  Date      Amount
1   Jan2012    100
1   Feb2012    110
1   April2012  150
```

and a dimension dimDate that contains all months in 2012.

When browsing my cube I see exactly what's above, but I would like to see one row to all dates on the dimDate dimension but, whats more important, I would like to see the March2012 row with the value 110 (last available value)

Is it something that can be done on the cube? I know it can be done on the DW by inserting a row for april or maybe with a left join query but I want to know if it can be done on the cube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a calculated measure. let's call it [CalcAmount] .the expression should be

```
IIF(ISNULL([Measures].[Amount]),[Measures].[Amount].PREVMEMBER,[Measures].[Amount])
```

hope that helps.